# How do I resolve acceleration issues with my Mahindra Bolero?

Tags: diesel, acceleration, mahindra

I have acceleration issues my Mahindra Bolero. This happened after I got the thermostat replaced. I have check with couple of workshops and ended up changing diesel filer and accelerator kit.

Acceleration drops all of a sudden while driving with headlights or park on. all I have to do is pump the accelerator peddle again and I am back in business.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Why was the thermostat replaced? Was the engine overheating? If the problem started after having it serviced, did you take it back to the shop that serviced it?

Answer (score 0):

Check for vaccum leaks. Move around the intake manifold, exhaust manifold and all hoses from imrc and pcv. Spray water while the engine is idling (on a cold start). 
Go to Mahindra if you can't check it.

Run a smoke test.

Comment: How should the OP go about checking for vacuum leaks? I think they are trying to avoid going to Mahindra, but maybe as a last resort. What else could the OP do to figure out what's going on?